# How should i post a picture with asset in tapestry?

Tags: tapestry

[[image]]

My pictures are situated in the folder 'images' which is a subfolder of 'layout' folder.
I placed the following line of code in my .tml page:

```html
<img src="${asset:layout:/images/img01.jpg}"/>
```

But i get this error: Could not convert 'asset:layout:/images/img01.jpg' into a component parameter binding: Unknown prefix for asset path 'layout:/images/img01.jpg'.
What should i do in this case because i have tried to move my pictures in other folders but the error appears again!

Comment: Made image inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<img src="${asset:context:/layout/images/img01.jpg}"/>` instead. Tapestry is right, `layout:` is not a valid prefix, it should be part of your path instead.

Comment: Thank you very much ! you are very smart !